# Collapsing Toolbar Image coming under status bar on recyclerview scroll down

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When the layout forms everything is fine, as in image is formed from status bar and status bar color is transparent. But whenever i scroll up and then scroll down the recycler view the image is scrolled till under status bar. But when i click on the image, it takes the original position.

Code for style/v21

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Code for collapsing toolbar layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ashish.swipemusic.GenreDetails">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerArtist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/album_details1"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_genre_details" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/genre_songs_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

[before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9yIO.png)

[after scroll down status bar appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG2eL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"` inside your `Toolbar`? I've tried this way and it works pretty well